# Genexus GAM - Login con Google

Tags: genexus

Estoy intentando usar GAM con Authentication Type = Google.

Algo estoy haciendo mal porque al iniciar con google (luego de poner usuario y password) me va al webpanel GAMExampleNotAuthorized.
El usuario es creado en el GAM correctamente, por lo que desestimo que se relacione con la configuración en Google cloud platform.

Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Finalmente resultó que me faltaba definir el rol necesario para acceder al webpanel que redirecciona la aplicación al loguearse.
Quedó resuelto.